# Application Publisher

Tags: android, google-play

I am about to finish my Android application. I would like to provide lite version and more complete paid pro version. Unfortunately, Google does not allow Australian developers to sell applications and I don't have any friends in US or UK.

Does anyone know of a person/company who would publish my pro application on my behalf? Google search did not bring up any results.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, any new comments on this? I'm looking for a publisher too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do NOT use androidpublisher.com. They publish many pirated apps and flood the market with absolutely horrible applications.  As a developer, "Android Publisher" is one of the last things you want associated with your application.

Answer (score 5):

Good news!  The Android Market opened up to Australian developers on September 30, 2010.

See this link:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/more-countries-more-sellers-more-buyers.html

Also, don't hesitate to deploy to other markets, such as the Amazon Appstore and SlideMe.

For any other countries that are still left out of selling on the Android Market, you can link from your free app to another market that does allow you to sell apps.  It's not as ideal, but it will get you into the game.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have found Android Publisher who would be willing to publish paid applications on behalf of developers who can not publish themselves due to Google's senseless restrictions  (so much for being open).

Android Publisher charge 19% service fees for publication services. This is additional to the 30% charge that Google charges to process paid applications. For example, if an application costs $0.99, Google would charge $0.30, Android Publisher would charge $0.19 and the developer keeps $0.50.

Whilst this isn't ideal I feel this is better then publishing on alternative market places as Android Market provides seamless experience and obviously there is much more exposure through Android Market.

In case someone else is interested the contact name is David and email address is: support@androidpublisher.com

As time passes I will keep updating this thread/question (unless the community doesn't want me to!) with my experience dealing with Android Publisher as it may help other developers who don't live in Google approved countries.

Answer (score 0):

I've found company that publishes games. I'm not sure I like their license terms though.

http://hyperbees.com/about/